# CSS Layout issue

Tags: css

I am attempting to style a page and its very close but I am a bit confused by one aspect. My pageWrapper div is set to take up 100% of the space with a fixed top of 49px, and currently a fixed bottom of 39px. Even though this renders very close to the desired effect the confusing part is that my footer div is only set to have a height of 24px. I would like to know where the extra 15 pixels is coming from. I suspect that it is a product of my researchTitle div class, but this is child element of a containing div and should not affect the parent element in this way. Below is my design code for formatting the layout

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Question.aspx.cs" Inherits="Question" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #header
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 49px;
            background: red;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #pageWrapper
        {
            position: absolute;
            height: auto;
            top: 49px;
            bottom: 39px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #questionTop
        {
            overflow: auto;
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 40%;
            background: blue;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #questionBottom
        {
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 35%;
            background: green;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #questionResearch
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 25%;
        }

        #terms, #refs, #auth
        {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #terms
        {
            left: 0;
            width: 34%;
        }
        #refs
        {
            left: 34%;
            width: 33%;
        }
        #auth
        {
            left: 67%;
            width: 33%;
        }
        .researchTitle
        {
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            height: 15px;
            background: #999;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .researchContent
        {
            position: relative;
            overflow: auto;
            background: #99C;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #footer
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 24px;
            bottom: 0;
            background: red;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div id="pageWrapper">
        <div id="questionTop">
            <p>
                First</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Last</p>
        </div>
        <div id="questionBottom">
            <p>
                First</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Last</p>
        </div>
        <div id="questionResearch">
            <div id="terms">
                <div class="researchTitle">
                    Terms</div>
                <div class="researchContent">
                    <p>
                        First</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Last</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="refs">
                <div class="researchTitle">
                    Refs</div>
                <div class="researchContent">
                    <p>
                        First</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Last</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="auth">
                <div class="researchTitle">
                    Authority</div>
                <div class="researchContent">
                    <p>
                        First</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Last</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div id="footer">
        Footer
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you setup a demo instead?

Comment: You're curious why 39px from the bottom is 15px away from the 24px height of the footer?

Comment: Where is the extra 15px showing up?

Comment: It pushes the questionResearch panel up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class researchContent height is set to 100% while the researchTitle is set to 15px height making it over 100% causing the terms class, which is 100% to go larger than expected.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   `"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #header
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 49px;
            background: red;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #pageWrapper
        {
            position: absolute;
            height: auto;
            top: 49px;
            bottom: 39px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #questionTop
        {
            overflow: auto;
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 40%;
            background: blue;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #questionBottom
        {
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 35%;
            background: green;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #questionResearch
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 28%;
        }

        #terms, #refs, #auth
        {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #terms
        {
            left: 0;
            width: 34%;
        }
        #refs
        {
            left: 34%;
            width: 33%;
        }
        #auth
        {
            left: 67%;
            width: 33%;
        }
        .researchTitle
        {
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            height: 12%;
            background: #999;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .researchContent
        {
            position: relative;
            overflow: auto;
            background: #99C;
            width: 100%;
            height: 88%;
        }
        #footer
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 24px;
            bottom: 0;
            background: red;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div id="pageWrapper">
        <div id="questionTop">
            <p>
                First</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Last</p>
        </div>
        <div id="questionBottom">
            <p>
                First</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Item</p>
            <p>
                Last</p>
        </div>
        <div id="questionResearch">
            <div id="terms">
                <div class="researchTitle">
                    Terms</div>
                <div class="researchContent">
                    <p>
                        First</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Last</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="refs">
                <div class="researchTitle">
                    Refs</div>
                <div class="researchContent">
                    <p>
                        First</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Last</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="auth">
                <div class="researchTitle">
                    Authority</div>
                <div class="researchContent">
                    <p>
                        First</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Item</p>
                    <p>
                        Last</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div id="footer">
        Footer
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So would I then have to wrap these panels in another div tag to split up the space?

Comment: Try that one.  Honestly it is not a good idea to use both % and pixels in the layout for height because it throws things off.  I am not sure exactly what you were trying to achieve but you should be able to see the title of the bottom three divs now

Comment: Thank you, you solution does not quite work when the screen is made smaller. Either way thank you for pointing out the issue!